# Why can't I iterate through nested keys?

Tags: python, loops

I have a dict:
`mydict = {1: {3: 'A', 4: 'B'}, 2: {11: {5:'B'}}}`

I'm trying to loop through the dict to be able to get the key that maps to `'B'` `({5:'B'})`.

However this loop isn't working and am getting an error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

```
for key in mydict.keys():
    for subkey in mydict[key].keys():
        for sub_subkey in mydict[key][subkey].keys():
            print(sub_subkey)
```

However when I run it manually, it works just fine:

`print(mydict[2][11].keys())` I get `5`

Comment: Change: `mydict[key][subkey].keys()` to: `mydict[key][subkey]` - do you see why ?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when `key` is 1 and `subkey` is 3, for example, because then you try to call `mydict[1][3].keys()` for the third nested loop, and the string `'A'` doesn't have a `keys()` method.

It's not immediately clear what you're trying to accomplish with these loops, so I'm not sure the best way to correct this problem in your particular case.  *"I'm trying to loop through the dict to be able to get the key that maps to `'B', ({5:'B'})`"* is a bit vague.

Comment: Oh makes sense, thanks! I changed it to `mydict[key][subkey].keys() to: mydict[key][subkey]`, but it prints out `A, B, 5`. How can I just have it print out the value that is a key to another value as `A` and `B` are not keys?

Comment: @eiobnrinb You need a recursive algorithm that tests whether the value is another dictionary. If it is, it recurses into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is different level of nested dictionaries.

You have two dictionaries in `mydict`, first one is dictionary itself and the other is again, dictionary of dictionaries.

So your loop is basically diving into third level, but when you take `mydict[1]` you receive "shallow" dictionary, which doesn't have dictionary in it, so calling `mydict[1].keys()` is OK, but going deeper, like `mydict[1][...]` will give you element, not dictionary, so you cannot call `keys()` method on it.

If you want all keys, that map to particular value, you could use some recursive search through dictionary of dictionaries:

```
def recursiveSearch(Dict, Value):
    if  Dict.__class__ != dict:
        return

    for key in Dict.keys():
        if(Dict[key].__class__ != dict):
            if(Dict[key] == Value):
                print(str(key) + ' : ' + str(Value))
        else:
            recursiveSearch(Dict[key], Value)
```